# не отрабатывает скрипт width

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется воттакая верстка

```
.progress.progress-striped.active
.bar#bar style=("width: 190px;")
```

Далее есть скрипт, где при достижении значения `width=190px` должен менятся уровень на +1 и `#bar` должен сбрасывать свою ширину до нуля.

Подскажите в  чем я ошибся. Заранее спасибо.

Вот скрипт:

```
bar = $("#bar");
if (bar == "195"){
  level = parseFloat($(".lvl-js").text());
  level++;
  $(".lvl-js").text(level);
  $("#bar").css('width', '0');
}
```

Comment: что значит bar == "195"?

Comment: может вместо `bar == "195"` поставить эето :  `bar.width() == "195"` ?

Comment: bar.width is not a function вот что пишет

Comment: @KonstantinVF а элемент с `id="bar"` у вас точно есть ?

Answer (score 0):

Немного поправил:

```
 var bar = $("#bar").width();
    if (parseInt(bar) == "195"){
      level = parseFloat($(".lvl-js").text());
      level++;
      $(".lvl-js").text(level);
      $("#bar").css('width', '0');
    }
```

Comment: попробовал, но так же все и осталось(

Answer (score 0):

```
if(bar[0].offsetWidth == "195"){
    .....
};
```

Попробуйте так.